# VBA to collate Identical rows in CSV

Tags: vba, excel, csv, excel-formula

I've got a csv file where some rows are repeatable. Task is to collate/(replace all and leave just one instance) with a number of repeats in the next cell. How do I do this with VBA?

f.e. something like this:

```
word, description
google, website
apple, fruit
google, website
```

Must convert into smth like this:

```
word, description
google, website, 2
apple, fruit
```

Comment: Are we allowed to sort the data first? That makes this a lot simpler!

Comment: Sure. Any reasonable algorithm for this would be a great help.

Comment: Are the data imported  into some worksheet already or you need help with the data import as well?

Comment: @exomen I wrote the subprocedure below for you WITHOUT the sorting step. If you sort the data first, it becomes even simpler and quicker. But the subprocedure below doesn't require the sorting. If you like it, please give it a thumbs up and mark it as "the answer"! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
Sub doCollate(iStartRow As Integer, iEndRow As Integer, iStartCol As Integer, iEndCol As Integer)

' Loop through the rows with values in them
For iSourceRow = iStartRow To iEndRow - 1

    ' Loop through the remaining rows to check
    For iCheckRow = iSourceRow + 1 To iEndRow

        ' Set a default variable
        bMatch = True

        ' Loop through the columns to check
        For iCol = iStartCol To iEndCol

            ' If these don't match or are blank, indicate that
            If Cells(iSourceRow, iCol) <> Cells(iCheckRow, iCol) _
                Or Cells(iSourceRow, iCol) = "" _
                Or Cells(iCheckRow, iCol) = "" Then
                bMatch = False
                Exit For    ' Exit the "For iCol = iStartCol to iEndCol" loop
            End If

        Next

        ' If there source row matches the destination row...
        If bMatch Then

            ' Increment the "counter"
            If Cells(iSourceRow, iEndCol + 1) = "" Then
                Cells(iSourceRow, iEndCol + 1) = "2"
            Else
                Cells(iSourceRow, iEndCol + 1) = Cells(iSourceRow, iEndCol + 1) + 1
            End If

            ' Clear the "check" row
            Range(Cells(iCheckRow, iStartRow), Cells(iCheckRow, iEndRow)).Clear

        End If

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

This could be optimized, since it rechecks blank rows that it produces, and it fails on rows that have blank cells on them, but for the example you gave it works perfectly.

Note that the column parameters are integers, not letters.  So column A=1, B=2, C=3, etc.